# XMLStreamConstants meaning of different field details

Tags: java, xml

I am sorry if this question was asked before. For clarification purpose, I have created this code below. In this code, there is a while loop which contains the switch statement. What I don't understand is in the switch statement, there are `START_ELEMENT`, `CHARACTER,` and also `END_ELEMENTS`. I want to know what that means and what is the purpose of `XMLStreamConstant` class. I have looked through the API ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamConstants.html)). In the API when looked at `START_ELEMENT`, all it is saying is Indicates an event is a start element which it didn't seems to explain that much. I have also included the XML document. In this case, what will be my start element, end elements and such? Thanks for the help

```
public class xmlStreamReaderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         List<Employee> empList = null;
            Employee currEmp = null;
            String tagContent = null;

            XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

            XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("employee.xml"));

            while(reader.hasNext()){


                int event = reader.next();

                switch(event){
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT:
                    empList = new ArrayList<>();

                    break;

                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                    if("employee".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
                        currEmp = new Employee(); 
                        currEmp.id = reader.getAttributeLocalName(0);  
                    }
                    if("employees".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
                        empList = new ArrayList<>(); //empList = []
                }

         break;
                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:

                    tagContent = reader.getText().trim(); 

                    break;

                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                    switch(reader.getLocalName()){
                      case "employee":
                        empList.add(currEmp); 
                        break;
                      case "firstName":
                        currEmp.firstName = tagContent; 
                        break;
                      case "lastName":
                        currEmp.lastName = tagContent; 
                        break;
                      case "location":
                        currEmp.location = tagContent;
                        break;
                    }

                    System.out.println(currEmp);


                    break;

                }

            }

            //print the employee list populated from XML
            for(Employee emp: empList){
                System.out.println(emp);
            }

}

}

class Employee{
      String id;
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      String location;

      @Override
      public String toString(){
        return firstName+" "+lastName;
      }
}
```

employee xml

```
<employees>
  <employee id="111">
    <firstName>Jammie</firstName>
    <lastName>Deng</lastName>
    <location>China</location>
  </employee>
  <employee id="112">
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Davis</lastName>
    <location>Russia</location>
  </employee>
  <employee id="113">
    <firstName>Peter</firstName>
    <lastName>Van</lastName>
    <location>Holland</location>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constants in `XMLStreamConstants` are used by the reader to notify you of what type of element it just read from your XML document.

If `event` is `XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT`, then the reader just read the opening tag of an XML element. In your example, this could be `<employees>` or any of the `<employee>`, `<firstName>`, `<lastName>`, or `<location>` tags.

Conversely, if `event` is `XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT`, then the reader just read the closing tag of an XML element. In your example, this could be `</employees>` or any of the `</employee>`, `</firstName>`, `</lastName>`, or `</location>` tags.

`START_DOCUMENT` and `END_DOCUMENT` just refer to the beginning and end of the whole XML document, respectively.

Finally, `CHARACTERS` refers to text in the document that isn't a comment or CDATA. In your example, this would be the content inside any of the `firstName`, `lastName`, or `location` tags.

Comment: good explanation !